# Algorithm for checking Prime Power

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Suppose we are given some arbitrary positive integer. How can we check whether the integer is a prime power?
Brute force would be very inefficient in this case.

Comment: Checking whether it's a perfect power at all isn't too inefficient. And if you know $n = b^k$, where $b$ is not a perfect power, checking whether $b$ is prime isn't very inefficient either.

Answer (score 2):

There are ["essentially linear time"](http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers.pdf) algorithms to check wether a number is a perfect power (see also [this paper](http://cr.yp.to/lineartime/powers2-20060914-ams.pdf)).

After that you can check wether the number is prime using one of the many known primality test (Miller-Rabin is probably the best combination of ease to implement and speed if you're not dealing with huge numbers)

Comment: Yes. But note that Miller-Rabin is a compositeness test, not a primality test.